# Difference between "npm run dev" and "npm start"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am very new to Node and AngularJS.

Can I know the difference between `npm run dev` and `npm start` commands in node terminal?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can look it up in the `package.json`. The section which you are looking for is named `scripts`.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is based on Next js, however, I think the case is similar to angular js in this regard

**npm run dev** is used to view or run the application worked on while in development mode to see active changes while **npm start** on the other hand cannot be run until **npm build** has been run which is usually when the project/ application has reached a **MVP** or presentation stage...the application is probably ready for use at that stage that's when npm start is used

Answer (score 4):

**npm start** is the same as **npm run start**,

so the question is what is the difference between **dev** and **start** options?

Firstly, **dev** and **start** are the properties of a package's **"scripts"** object in the **package.json** file (in the root of the project)

Secondly, in general, the command which will be executed depends on the value which is set to the **dev** or **start** property.

For instance, the **next.js project** predefined the following values:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
```

, where
**"next dev"** starts the application **in development mode** with hot-code reloading, error reporting, ond more.
**"next start"** starts the application **in production mode** (if the application is already compiled.)

And thirdly, if the **"scripts"** object does not define a **"start"** property, **npm** will run **node server.js**.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run dev` is often associated with development-specific tasks, while `npm start` is more aligned with starting the application in a production environment.

Comment: Answer is correct but, if you can explain more its good for better understanding for others.